# Hibernate Criteria problems with order by and joins

Tags: hibernate, sql-order-by, criteria

I have a Hibernate entity "Contract", which has a set of "ContractVersions" (one-to-many mapping). Here is a shortened mapping:

```
<class name="Contract">
    <set name="versions" order-by="version_id" mutable="false" lazy="false" fetch="join">
        <key column="contract_id" not-null="true"/>
        <one-to-many class="ContractVersion"/>
    </set>
</class>
```

I then make a Criteria that does contract search and want to order the results by date:

```
criteria.addOrder(Order.desc("createdAt"));
```

However, when I look at the generated SQL, I see a problem. Hibernate uses ˇleft outer joinˇ to select contracts with versions and adds both orderings:

```
... order by version4_.version_id, this_.created_at desc ...
```

For me, ordering by date is more important. Is there a way to solve this problem?

Comment: Having this same problem now... Thinking of removing the order-by on the one to many, but I'm hoping there is a better solution

Comment: Encountered this as well.  Have not found a good solution besides ordering the resulting list in memory.